# How can I output all except the first character of a Go template key or field?

Tags: go, docker

Provided a key or field, is it possible to perform some string manipulation before its output using the Go text/template engine. This is to improve the template in [this](https://gist.github.com/efrecon/8ce9c75d518b6eb863f667442d7bc679) gist, which aims at recreating the `docker run` command that led to a container through running `docker inspect`. The leading `--name={{.Name}} \` does not fully work as it outputs a leading slash, a slash character that needs to be removed to recreate a container with the same name.

As this can only be based on the templating facility that is built in docker, I cannot use external functions or similar.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you mean by "templating facility that is built in docker". Could you use [Funcs](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs) to register a custom function?

Comment: No, I cannot extend what templates can do through Funcs. I would have to convince people from the docker project that such a function would be a "good-things-to-have".

Comment: Understood. Did not know about `--format` from docker [inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/)